# How to automatically add a newline after the program's output on the terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: The screenshot of my VS Code]

Whenever I run the code, the output will be printed out, and immediately after the prompt for the path will be printed on the same line.

How do I display the path in a new line after printing the output?

Comment: Add the new line char `'\n'` at the end of the output.

Comment: Can you type the code in rather than add a screenshot of it?

Answer (score 1):

A way to force this behavior independently of the program output is to add a new line character before the [bash custom prompt](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Bash/Prompt_customization). In order to achieve this, you must simply reset the `PS1` environment variable at your terminal.

```bash
PS1='\n'$PS1
```

Now, after every command in your terminal, a new line will be added before showing the prompt. If you want to perpetuate this behavior every time you open a terminal, you must add this line into your `.bashrc` config file located in your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

Add `\n` to print a *new line* character like this:

```
printf("asdfg\n");
```

The `\` indicates an escape character: there are other possible values (details [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/escape))

Comment: yes it works if i add \n in the code ... but my frds and in youtube tutorials they got path in next line without \n

Comment: means I want to ask is there any other way like in settings or i can install some files which will help me

Answer (score 0):

Go to your setting, type "code-runner.executorMap" this in search-box
click edit in settings.johnson

[Click on Edit in settings.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7NgK.png)
then add
"; echo -e"

[At the end of line whatever language you code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhGHS.png)